# Power series representation for $x\arctan(x)$. How?

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am supposed to start with the P.S representation for $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and then figure out the P.S representation for $x\tan^{-1}(x)$. I know the process of making it for just the $\tan^{-1}x$. But wouldn't the fact that there is an extra $x$ at the front change everything dramatically? Or am I not getting something?

Can I just do the same process as for $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and then just add an extra $x$ after sigma?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can just multiply. Get $x$ inside the sum and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that 
$$\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$
We also know that, for $|t|<1$,
$$\frac1t=\sum_{k\geq0}(1-t)^k$$
So we then have that 
$$\frac1{1+t^2}=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^kt^{2k}$$
So for $|x|<1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan x=&\int_0^x\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^kt^{2k}dt\\
=&\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\int_0^xt^{2k}dt\\
=&\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Which means that 
$$x\arctan x=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+2}}{2k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan^{-1}x=\int\frac1{1+x^2}=\int\sum_n(-x^2)^n=\sum_n\int(-x^2)^n=\sum_n(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.
Thus $x\cdot\tan^{-1}x=\sum_n(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+1}$.